# How to add an ionic project to an nx workspace?

Tags: monorepo, nx-workspace

I have an Nx v15.9.2 workspace, to which I added a nestjs server using `nx g @nrwl/nest:app my-nest-app`.

I want to add an **ionic** project to my nx workspace, but I haven't found a good way to do this. I checked certain tutorials online, such as: [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@eric.jeker/how-to-integrate-ionic-in-nrwl-nx-3493fcb7e85e) (uses `@nrwl/angular`) and [this tutorial](https://ionic.io/blog/ionic-angular-monorepos-with-nx) (that uses `@nxtend/ionic-angular` from https://nxtend.dev/ plugins that focuses on enabling Ionic and Capacitor development in an Nx workspace) but the tutorials and plugins are outdated and don't work with Nx v15 workspace.

How can I create an ionic (Capacitor) project to my existing nx workspace?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? Have you tried : https://github.com/nxext/nx-extensions ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I think any answer to this question would be outdated a few weeks later. As of Februari 6th Nx 18.0 has come out 4 days ago and there is currently no way to integrate an Ionic project with Nx. That said I'll give you some pointers to help figure out how to add ionic to your workspace at the time of writing that may or may not still be useful in the future.

### Nxtend is dead

The `@nxtend` plugins have been renamed/moved and are now part of `@nxext`, the ionic/capacitor specifically are now located in [this repository](https://github.com/nxext/nx-extensions-ionic). This means anyone with looking to add ionic to a recent version of nx needs the `@nxext/ionic` and `@nxext/capacitor` packages.

### A solution that works today

You can use a Nx 17 workspace to use the `@nxext` packages.

```
npx create-nx-workspace@17.3.1
npm install --save-dev --exact @nxext/ionic-angular
nx generate @nxext/ionic-angular:application my-cool-app
```

### Where to find documentation?

The npm page for `@next/ionic` still links to an old site which no longer
To save an searching souls some time I'll say that as of feb 6th 2024 The documentation for `@nxext/ionic` [is hosted here](https://nxext.github.io/nx-extensions-ionic/). There is another website named [nxext.dev](https://nxext.dev/) which used to host the ionic packages documentation (and still claims to on its home page) and is still recommended by Google, but this site no longer has the ionic documentation.
The maintainer said he has plans to unify all the nxext documentation again on this site in the future, so if this answer is particularly old you might still want to check it.